# click on text a dialog box must open

Tags: android, dialog

i want to open a dialog box on click on text, like if i click on android a dialog box must open and all discription is given about android in that dialog box, same as that i want it for my app, so what shoul i do, please help,
thanks in advance......

this is my code for `dialog box` :

```
 public void webapp(View V)
       {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Aboutus.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_app);
            dialog.setTitle("WebApp");

            tvaboutwebapp=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvaboutwebapp);

            // Set On ClickListener
            tvaboutwebapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
       }
```

[image]

Comment: please help me in this code!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to make out, what you are trying to do.

Comment: `i want to open a dialog box on click on text, like if i click on android a dialog box must open and all discription is given about android in that dialog box` - what are you trying to say ? Please elaborate this..

Comment: if i click on any of the title a dialog box should be open and all details shouls be in that dialog.. contents of that dialog..

Comment: " all details should be in that dialog " you need another xml file for managing you custom dialog box . who calls your webapp () method ? it may be called from another textView's setOnItemClickListner() .this textView would be you title.

Comment: i done this thing but i get an error in that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `dialog.show();` outside `OnClickListener(..)`.

Your code should be like this.

```
 tvaboutwebapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: in dialog box it should show the xml file of webapp what should i do for this?

Comment: Is it possible to click on TextView which is child of dialog before showing the actual dialog box?

Comment: You can try with custom dialog ..[android-custom-dialog-example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: i had used the custom dialog but getting an error on clicking the text i had upload my errorlog in my question please check it and help me... thank you...

Comment: tvaboutwebapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_app);
    dialog.setTitle("Websites & apps");
    
    TextView tvwebapp = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvwebapp);
    
    dialog.show();
    
   }
  });

Comment: Use `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Aboutus.this);` instead of `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());`

Answer (score 1):

Show `Dialog` on `TextView onClick()` event:

```
tvaboutwebapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TextView  tvaboutwebapp;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvaboutwebapp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.helloword);

       // Set On ClickListener
       tvaboutwebapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
               Showdialog();
           }
       });

     //  dialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
void Showdialog()
{
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.demo, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert!");
    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final TextView txt = (TextView) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",new               DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {

                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();


}

  }
```